# Create an enumerable of generic classes with differing concrete implementations

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a decorator interface and three concrete classes that implement it:

```
public interface IWorksheetItem
{
}

public class WorksheetItem1 : IWorksheetItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public class WorksheetItem2 : IWorksheetItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public class WorksheetItem3 : IWorksheetItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TimeStamp2 { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a generic worksheet class as follows:

```
public class Worksheet<T> where T : IWorksheetItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    public Type ItemType => typeof(T);
}
```

Let's say I create the following three worksheets:

```
var worksheet1 = new Worksheet<WorksheetItem1>
{
    Name = "Worksheet1",
    Items = new List<WorksheetItem1>
    {
        new WorksheetItem1 { Id = 1, Name = "Name 1", TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow },
        new WorksheetItem1 { Id = 2, Name = "Name 2", TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow },
        new WorksheetItem1 { Id = 3, Name = "Name 3", TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow }
    }
};

var worksheet2 = new Worksheet<WorksheetItem2>
{
    Name = "Worksheet2",
    Items = new List<WorksheetItem2>
    {
        new WorksheetItem2 { Id = 1, First = "First 1", Last = "Last 1", TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow },
        new WorksheetItem2 { Id = 2, First = "First 2", Last = "Last 2", TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow },
        new WorksheetItem2 { Id = 3, First = "First 3", Last = "Last 3",TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow }
    }
};

var worksheet3 = new Worksheet<WorksheetItem3>
{
    Name = "Worksheet3",
    Items = new List<WorksheetItem3>
    {
        new WorksheetItem3 { Id = 1, Company = "Company 1", TimeStamp1 = DateTime.UtcNow },
        new WorksheetItem3 { Id = 2, Company = "Company 2", TimeStamp1 = DateTime.UtcNow },
        new WorksheetItem3 { Id = 3, Company = "Company 3", TimeStamp1 = DateTime.UtcNow }
    }
};
```

Is it possible to define a parameter that can contain all three within an IEnumerable? I tried something like this, but I can't figure out how to actually pass in the worksheets as a collection:

```
public byte[] GetSpreadSheet<T>(IEnumerable<Worksheet<T>> worksheets) where T : IWorksheetItem
{
    foreach (var worksheet in worksheets)
    {
        // I need to reflect inside here to sniff out DateTime and DateTime? properties
        var pi = worksheet.ItemType.GetProperties();
    }
}
```

The following results in "cannot convert from 'Worksheet' to 'Worksheet' errors when trying to add to the list.

```
var worksheets = new List<Worksheet<IWorksheetItem>>();
worksheets.Add(worksheet1);
worksheets.Add(worksheet2);
worksheets.Add(worksheet3);
```

I understand the compiler error, but I'm having a brain block on how I can accomplish what I'm wanting. I need to pass an unknown number of worksheets into my GetSpreadsheet() method. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you're going to have to create the following interface:

```
public interface IWorksheet
{
    string Name { get; }
    IEnumerable<IWorksheetItem> Items { get; }
}
```

Now you redefine your `Worksheet<T>` class like this:

```
public class Worksheet<T> : IWorksheet where T : IWorksheetItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IWorksheetItem> IWorksheet.Items => this.Items.Cast<IWorksheetItem>();
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And then finally, your `GetSpreadSheet` can be written as such:

```
public byte[] GetSpreadSheet<T>(IEnumerable<IWorksheet> worksheets) where T : IWorksheetItem
{
    foreach (var worksheetItem in worksheets.SelectMany(ws => ws.Items))
    {
        if (worksheetItem is WorksheetItem1 worksheetItem1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{worksheetItem1.Name}");
        }
        else if (worksheetItem is WorksheetItem2 worksheetItem2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{worksheetItem2.First} {worksheetItem2.Last}");
        }
        else if (worksheetItem is WorksheetItem3 worksheetItem3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{worksheetItem3.Company}");
        }
    }
    return /* ??? */;
}
```